# RHC client tool for windows error while setup

Tags: ruby, openshift, openshift-client-tools

I followed all the steps as mentioned on the openshift page for guide on installing the client tool.

after doing gem `install rhc`, when i give the command `rhc setup` following error is shown.

```
C:\Users\me>rhc setup --debug
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require': cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:5:in '<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:22:in '<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:4:in '<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4:in '<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:11:in '<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/ssh_helpers.rb:18:in '<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:77:in '<class:Wizard>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:7:in '<module:RHC>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/wizard.rb:6:in '<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands/base.rb:4:in '<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands/account.rb:2:in '<module:Commands>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands/account.rb:1:in '<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in 'require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands.rb:189:in 'block in load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands.rb:188:in 'each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands.rb:188:in 'load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/cli.rb:36:in 'start'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/bin/rhc:20:in '<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in 'load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in '<main>'
```

am i doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably an issue caused by using Ruby 2.2. If you switch back to Ruby 2.1 (or earlier) this issue will likely go away.