# Openshift RHC setup throws error

Tags: ruby, openshift-client-tools

After successfully installing rhc, when I try to

```
rhc setup
```

and I get the following console output:

[image]

Anyone any idea why this happens?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please remove the screenshot and replace it with the text of the error, or at least add the first couple lines; examine those for relevancy and remove anything not directly related. Screenshots can't be searched, can't be copied/pasted and when the link breaks and the image disappears the question becomes nonsensical. What did you find when you researched the stated cause of the problem? If you found hits, what happened when you tried the solutions? We need to know those things so please add that information to the answer.

Comment: Also, you may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29919144/rhc-client-tool-for-windows-error-while-setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so after further investigation how I fixed this was:

```
rhc ssh *my_app_name*
```

after which I ran

```
tail_all
```

This gave me a pretty extensive error log generated by the openshift server.

Silly error - turned out it was just a missing dependency from the `package.json` file :)